# Adding a row to a growing database pre-release.

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have the database already finished and I would like to add a few rows that are present on the first time opening the app. The main issue, not knowing where in the application to implement this.  For example, when the user opens the app for the first time, there is an example item.  The item can be deleted.  After the row is deleted it will never show up again.  I am using Androrm (object relational mapper) [androrm home page](http://www.androrm.com/).  My main question: How do I add a single row to the database (where & how) before release.  Within the onCreate, will add a row each time, the class is opened.

Took out most code to make it simple.

**Implementation**

```
public class LogFirst extends Model {

    protected CharField db_oneName;
    public LogFirst() {
        super(true);
        db_oneName = new CharField(80);

    }

    public void setDB_oneName(String name1) {
        db_oneName.set(name1);
    }

    public String getDB_oneName() {
        return db_oneName.get();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return db_oneName.get();
    }


    public static List<LogFirst> all() {
        return LogFirst.objects().all().toList();
    }

    public static QuerySet<LogFirst> objects() {
        return LogFirst.objects(context(), LogFirst.class);
    }

    public boolean save() {
        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmhhss");
        String id = formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + "";
        return this.save(context(), Integer.valueOf(id));
    }


    public boolean delete() {
        return this.delete(context());
    }


    private static Context context() {
        return ExtendsActivity.context();
    }
}
```

**Saving**

```
LogFirst lf = new LogFirst();
lf.setDB_oneName(name.getText().toString());
lf.save();
```

**Adapter**

```
public class LogFirstAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LogFirst> {
    Context mContext;
    List<LogFirst> mLogs;

    public LogFirstAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<LogFirst> logs) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        mLogs = logs;
    }


    public void setLogs(List<LogFirst> logs) {
        mLogs = logs;
    }


    public List<LogFirst> getLogs() {
        return mLogs;
    }


    public void add(LogFirst log) {
        mLogs.add(log);
    }


    public void remove(LogFirst log) {
        mLogs.remove(log);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return mLogs.size();
    }


    public LogFirst getItem(int position) {
        return mLogs.get(position);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LogFirstRow view = (LogFirstRow) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new LogFirstRow(mContext);
        }
        LogFirst log = getItem(position);
        view.setLog(log);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd do something like that in a migration. I'm not familiar with Androrm but it looks like they have some support for migration: http://www.androrm.com/documentation/models/migrations/

Try putting in the code to create the new records in the overriden `migrate` function. The docs say migrations will be kept track of but I'm not sure how it will play out so test to see what happens.